# Accessing types defined in the implementation part of another unit

Tags: delphi, calendar, firemonkey

I'm in Delphi Firemonkey subclassing the FMX.Calendar.Style in order to add more functionality to the TCalendar component. I want to add 'drag select' multiple days (a day range). I have a rough working proof of principle. I'm subclassing TStyledCalendar in FMX.Calendar.Style in another unit.

In order to extract a selected day, I need to cast to TDayItem. The problem is that the type TDayItem in defined in the implementation part and therefore not accessible in the other unit with the new class.

Is there a way to access it anyway?

```
unit FMX.Calendar.Style;

interface

{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}

uses
  System.Classes, .., ..

type

{ TStyledCalendar }

  TStyledCalendar = class(TStyledPresentation)
  public const
    CountOfVisibleDays = 6 * 7;
..
..
..
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, .. ..

type
  TDayItem = class(TListBoxItem)
  private
    FDate: TDateTime;
  public
    property Date: TDateTime read FDate write FDate;
  end;

..

..
```

Comment: You can read more and download the resulting drag select component here:  https://github.com/Spelt/drag-select-fmx-calendar/
If you like it click the like :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is simply no way for a unit to access a type (or a variable, or a constant) that is declared in another unit's `implementation` section.  Only items that are declared in a unit's `interface` section are accessible to other units.  A unit's `implementation` section is accessible only to the unit which it belongs to.

In this situation, you have two choices:

- copy the declaration of `TDayItem` into your own unit, and then type-cast the ListBox items to that type as needed.  And then check FMX's declaration of `TDayItem` for changes in every new release/patch so you can update your code accordingly.
- make a copy of `FMX.Calander.Style.pas` and add the copy to your project.  Then, you can freely alter the copy's `implementation` (but not its `interface`!) however you want. During compiling, your copied unit will take priority over the original unit.  Note: this approach only works if you are NOT building with Runtime Packages enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Yes copying the declaration and typecasting works.   But a special note: 
This cast is working:
var dayItem := TDayItem(Sender);   

This cast is not working
var dayItem := Sender as TDayItem; 

I will think some more about the solution to choose.  Its probably more wise to copy the the original  FMX.Calander.Style.pas file in the project and do the inheritance in that copied file.

Comment: @Edward "*This [`as`] cast is not working*" - correct, because `FMX.Calendar.Style.TDayItem` and `MyUnit.TDayItem` are separate and unrelated types, as far as the compiler is concerned. The ListBox items will not be instances of `MyUnit.TDayItem`, hence `Sender as MyUnit.TDayItem` fails since it validates the cast at runtime, whereas `MyUnit.TDayItem(Sender)` is a static cast at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise explaining.

Comment: See: https://github.com/Spelt/drag-select-fmx-calendar/ for the resulting drag select TCalendar extension